# Breeze saving strategy

Tags: angularjs, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating my first spa with angular and breeze. So for so good and i'm very happy with the progress I've made. But now I'm stuck on my editing and saving my entity product (example class below). When I edit a product i also call the related products, and I have a checkbox (on saving) that says "override related products with same info". But what is the best way to do this? Server side? Should i expand the model on the client side? Are there examples available?

**Product:**

```
public class Product
{
    #region Fields

    private ICollection<ProductCategory> _productCategories;
    private ICollection<ProductManufacturer> _productManufacturers;
    private ICollection<ProductPicture> _productPictures;
    private ICollection<ProductSpecificationAttribute> _productSpecificationAttributes;
    private ICollection<ProductTierPrice> _productTierPrices;

    #endregion Fields

    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public int ParentGroupedProductId { get; set; }
    public bool VisibleIndividually { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool LimitedToStores { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? SpecialPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
    public bool HasTierPrices { get; set; }
    public TaxRate TaxRate { get; set; }
    public bool SyncToShop { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateChanged { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Mapping

    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories
    {
        get { return _productCategories ?? (_productCategories = new List<ProductCategory>()); }
        protected set { _productCategories = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductManufacturer> ProductManufacturers
    {
        get { return _productManufacturers ?? (_productManufacturers = new List<ProductManufacturer>()); }
        protected set { _productManufacturers = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductPicture> ProductPictures
    {
        get { return _productPictures ?? (_productPictures = new List<ProductPicture>()); }
        protected set { _productPictures = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductSpecificationAttribute> ProductSpecificationAttributes
    {
        get { return _productSpecificationAttributes ?? (_productSpecificationAttributes = new List<ProductSpecificationAttribute>()); }
        protected set { _productSpecificationAttributes = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductTierPrice> ProductTierPrices
    {
        get { return _productTierPrices ?? (_productTierPrices = new List<ProductTierPrice>()); }
        protected set { _productTierPrices = value; }
    }

    #endregion Mapping
}
```

**Related Product:**

```
public class RelatedProduct
{
    #region Fields

    #endregion Fields

    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId1 { get; set; }
    public int ProductId2 { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }

    #endregion Properties

    //#region Mapping

    //public virtual Product Product1 { get; set; }
    //public virtual Product Product2 { get; set; }

    //#endregion Mapping
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture Changes of All Products in Clinent Jquery Array and send to Server Side..

Serverside change your controller method argument to IEnumerable products , so you can save all changes in Batch

If you want to update only change value use HttpPatch on server side and update changed value only